# I2S MEMS Microphone pop sound at the beginning of the recording

Tags: i2s, microphone, arecord

I am using [Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3421) in Raspberry Pi 4 running raspbian buster. I installed it successfully [following adafruit guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-mems-microphone-breakout/raspberry-pi-wiring-test). It is working well for recording using arecord.

However, every time I start a recording it starts with a "pop" sound.
Here is how the waveform looks like:

[image]

If you have any suggestion or if you already encounter this issue, I would really appreciate your help.